# Using GridBagLayout to arrange components of a JPanel vertically

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm making a program. Is it is possible to arrange components of a `JPanel` vertically?

This is for a label. I would like a label to be shown on top of a text field without having to create another `JPanel` for it. Also, I am using `GridBagLayout` and `CardLayout` to arrange and switch out my `JPanels`.

Comment: The answer is yes...

Comment: You probably could use a BoxLayout for this as well.  C.f. `Box.createVerticalBox()`.

Comment: `GridBagConstraints`. Add a component with the constraints, increase `gridy` on the constraints, then add the next one with the same constraints. Check out [How to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to learn how to use the layout

Comment: You could also use a `VerticalLayout` from the SwingLabs SwingX project, but that would depend on your requirements

Comment: @AndrewThompson *"would like to know if it is possible"* ... I assume ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Oh riiight...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `GridBagConstraints#gridwidth` set to `GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER`...

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
add(new JLabel("Happy as can be"), gbc);
add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
add(new JLabel("Happy place"), gbc);
// etc..
```

Take a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Set GridBagLayout's options: Columns Weight [1]; Rows Height [30, 40, 50, 1] for each line a specified value of height you want, last row put 1 to using Rows Weight and set its Rows Weight [0, 0, 0, 1] then set component's anchor to northwest, Fill: horizontal or both; Finally set component X, Y to put component to grid bag

Comment: I'd need to see that, to believe it (would work).  Got code and a screen shot?

Comment: Okay, I like to think I'm pretty good with `GridBagLayout`, but your answer just confuses me...

Comment: See here http://pastebin.com/BgPBTsG1 run inside a class extends jpanel or add your jpanel name to setBorder, setLayout, add (for screen shot run it hehe)